# How can I detect proxy was configured for build agent?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, proxy, azure-pipelines

I have simple powershell task that read artifact and uploads the blob using `Set-AzStorageBlobContent`.

To detect a proxy I'm using the pipeline variable with proxy url value like below (this is the inline PowerShell script)

```
if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty("$(proxyUrl)"))
{
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy $(proxyUrl);
Write-Host "proxy " $(proxyUrl);
}
```

It initializes global `DefaultWebProxy` if the `proxyUrl` parameter value was set.

However I've [configured a build agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) to be running with the `--proxyurl` parameter already .

`./config.cmd --proxyurl http://localhost:8080`

I'd like to remove the `proxyUrl` pipeline variable and get the proxy from a build agent configuration. I do not want to use global environment variable (`set http_proxy`) since it requires to set proxy name twice (for the agent and for the environment variable).

I'd like to have the possibility to change Agent pool (between hosted and private e.g.) and do not to modify pipeline proxy variable name.

Is it possible to check was a build agent configured with the proxy from the PowerShell task executed by the agent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the `AGENT_PROXYURL` env variable (checking the `gci env:` powershell command output)